# From where payment html coming in order related email?

Tags: magento2

From where payment html coming inn order related template?

Code for payment HTML:

```
{{var payment_html|raw}}
```

I already checked

> /vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/templates/info/default.phtml

file but it is calling for the admin order only. It it not calling for the front end orders.

Answer (score 0):

It is render from 
`vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php`
there is a function `prepareTemplate`

```
$transport = [
        'order' => $order,
        'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
        'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
        'store' => $order->getStore(),
        'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
        'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
    ];
```

Comment: But when I add {{var payment_html|raw}} this code into order-related email template then payment email is stretching into outlook mail also credit card word added into top header

Can you please advise? what is the exact issue.

Comment: upload screenshot of email

Comment: Update the question with a screenshot.
Please check.

Comment: Have same problem with Laybuy module.
Possible Solution: Make a plugin that will truncate the string or remove it entirely..
```
Magento_Sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/InvoiceSender.

    /**
     * Return payment info block as html
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getPaymentHtml(Order $order)
    {
        return $this->paymentHelper->getInfoBlockHtml(
            $order->getPayment(),
            $this->identityContainer->getStore()->getStoreId()
        );
    }

```

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem with Laybuy module.
Possible Solution: Make a plugin that will truncate the string or remove it entirely..

```
Magento_Sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/InvoiceSender.

    /**
     * Return payment info block as html
     *
     * @param Order $order
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getPaymentHtml(Order $order)
    {
        return $this->paymentHelper->getInfoBlockHtml(
            $order->getPayment(),
            $this->identityContainer->getStore()->getStoreId()
        );
    }
```